# Python Flask - render_template not displaying values passed

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to Python and trying to develop simple web application.

In the code below I am trying to retrieve values from DB and rending on HTML page
I'm able to see the HTML page but not values passed. Please help me here. 
Python code

```
      @app.route('/userDetails', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
     def userDetails():

     if request.method == 'POST':
print('in get method')
userid = request.form['userId']
print('user id ', userid)
conn = mysql.connect()
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Get User Details
print('execut sql')
result = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE user_id= %s", [userid])
if result > 0:
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in data:
        userId = row[0]
        name = row[1]
        userName = row[2]
        password = row[3]
        return render_template("userDetails.html", userId=userId, name=name, userName=userName, password=password)
else:
    return render_template('index.html')

cursor.close()
```

HTML code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
  <head>
    <title>Python Flask Bucket List App</title>


    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

      <h3 class="text-muted">Python Flask App </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="jumbotron">
          <h1>Display User Details</h1>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <form class=class="form-userDetails, action="/userDetails", method="POST">
                User ID:<input type="text" name="userId" class="form-control">
                Name <output name="name" id="name" for="userId" class="form-control"></output>
                User Name <output name="userName" id="userName" for="userId" class="form-control"></output>
                Password <output name="password" id="password" for="userId" class="form-control"></output>
                </br>
                <button id="btnretive" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Retrive</button>

            </form>
     </div>

      <div class="Footer">
          <footer class="footer">
            <p>&copy; Company 2015</p>
          </footer>
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Python code added for reference

Comment: Please show how you pass values into template?

Comment: return render_template("userDetails.html", userId=userId, name=name, userName=userName, password=password). I have added python code now

Comment: And where are you actually displaying the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DRaj, you are using `<output>` tag in incorrect way. From the specification,

> The HTML Output element () is a container element into which a site or app can inject the results of a calculation or the outcome of a user action.

For more info and example refer to this [Mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output).

---

Now, 
Flask uses **Jinja2 template engine** for its HTML rendering. So, the correct way to output values would be to enter a python variable inside **Expression delimiters** `{{ ... }}` in the HTML and pass the variables to `render_template` method.

i.e.

```html
<form class=class="form-userDetails, action="/userDetails", method="POST">
    User ID:<input type="text" name="userId" class="form-control">
    Name: {{ name }}
    User Name: {{ userName }}
    Password: {{ password }}
    </br>
    <button id="btnretive" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Retrive</button>

</form>
```

and the python code should be:-

```py
return render_template("userDetails.html", name=name, userName=userName, password=password)
```

Refer to this [Jinja template designer documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates) for more information.